# Linq Query a list of Objects in VB.NET to get the biggest difference between two numbers

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of Objects in VB.NET which includes two properties, `number1` and `number2`.

I try to find the biggest difference between those two numbers and return the numbers in the following format: `number1 - number2`

What I have been able to do is to find the biggest difference like that:

```
Dim biggestDifference AS String = samples.Max(Function(x) Math.Abs(x.number1 - x.number2))
```

However, this returns just the difference. For example, if the biggest difference belongs to the object with `number1 = 10 and number2 = 3`, I would like to get `10 - 3`, while I get `7` now.

Any idea how I can continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim winning_object = _
    samples.OrderByDescending(Function(x) Math.Abs(x.number1 - x.number2)).First()
Dim biggestDifference As String = $"{winning_object.number1} - {winning_object.number2}"
```

Comment: I added an extra line to put the answer into the format the OP wanted, feel free to undo if you don't like it